# AppleScript->echo into terminal --can it be seen in logs?

Tags: terminal, logs

I don't know if this question is better off on here, or in the Apple/Mac world... but I do need a decent answer.

I am using Applescript to pull data from fields in a spreadsheet or database, and shove them directly into terminal:

```
echo "thisismydatastring and my saltbits" | openssl aes-256-cbc -k thisismypassword -base64
```

My question: is there a way one could filter thru the log files to catch this plaintext instance of the password?

Is there a better way to prevent hacking?

PS:  and for the love of pete, if you're smart (or snarky) enough to offer to edit my writing, at least offer a sane answer to the question.

Comment: You could start by checking your ~/.bash_history to see which commands appear.

Comment: editing questions so that they conform to the formatting conventions used here is **not** "snarky".  It's helping you (and it's helping other users of this site).  Many people here just ignore badly formatted questions.  Your friendly editor Jesse_b saved your question from that.   editing questions is a valuable service for this site and can be done by people who don't know the answer to a question.

Comment: thx for the ~/.bash_history nugget.. it seems the command does NOT appear there, which is encouraging.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310068/applescript-echo-into-openssl-aes-encryption-is-there-a-way-to-crack-snoop-t

Comment: wasn't sure which place to put this question.. apologies for the multipost.. While this is an "Apple-ish" thing (ie., applescript), most Apple users simply don't even know what Terminal is, nevermind what it does... I figured folks here would know far more.... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your password in your shell history (or easily trawled from `ps`) then **don't put the password on the command line**.

One alternative is to put the password in a file, set the permissions to 600 with `chmod` and use `$(cat passwordfile)` in place of the password on the command line.

This is not safe if you don't trust root on your system, or if you think that other users on the system may be capable of acquiring root privileges.

e.g.

- edit `/.mysecretpassword` and add your password.
- `chmod 600 ~/.mysecretpassword`
- run:

  ```
  echo "thisismydatastring and my saltbits" | 
    openssl aes-256-cbc -k "$(cat ~/.mysecretpassword)" -base64
  ```

Similarly, if `"thisismydatastring and my saltbits"` is sensitive, don't put that on the command line either.  put it in a file and pipe it into `openssl`.

`openssl` has an option to read the password from a file descriptor.  This is mostly useful if you write a wrapper script to run openssl.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# use file descriptor 99 for no particular reason. a completely arbitrary choice,
# as long as it's not already in use (probably isn't).
exec 99< ~/.mysecretpassword

openssl aes-256-cbc -base64 -k fd:99
```

Save that somewhere in your $PATH, make it executable with `chmod` (700 is probably best if you are worried about snoopers) and you can pipe or redirect your data into it.  It's probably slightly better than the `$(cat ...)` method because it doesn't name `~/.mysecretpassword` on any command line (so that won't be saved in history or visible in `ps`).

This file-descriptor method is still only security-by-obscurity, so isn't safe against an untrusted root account or users who can gain root.

You can improve the security a bit by using an encrypted filesystem that you mount manually (and type in the pass-phrase manually...and hope nobody's logging your keystrokes) when you need it, and unmount when finished.  Applescript implies you're using a Mac - dunno how you'd do this on OS X but on Linux, you'd use FUSE if you didn't have root on the machine.

It's generally considered a bad idea to be doing crypto stuff on a machine that you don't completely control, or that has other (potentially hostile) users on it.  (for more secure crypto, don't do it on a machine connected to a network...better yet, use a un-networked machine in a faraday cage in a lead-lined room at the bottom of a 100' deep concrete bunker.  transfer the base64 encrypted data by floppy - not a USB device - or via QR code...printed or display the QR on screen and scan with phone)

More simply: if you have any reason to suspect that you can't completely trust the machine you're on, and it is important that the data stays secret, then don't use it for encryption.  There's lots of ways to make a mistake, and it only takes one to be completely compromised.

---

BTW, if you're using `bash`, you can remove individual lines from the `~/.bash_history` **before** you exit that shell by hitting up-arrow until you see the line you want to remove and then typing <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> and hitting up-arrow again.

Alternatively, you can clear that shell session's entire history by running `history -c` **before** you exit that shell.  This will not clear anything already saved into the .bash_history file.

If the password or other sensitive data is already saved to your .bash_history then your only option will be to delete or edit your history file when you login again.  NOTE: It may already be backed up or snapshotted - i.e. too late to fix.

Comment: i forgot to mention that the bunker should have a "Beware of the leopard" sign.

Comment: I should've mentioned that this encryption engine is being used by AppleScript, called from within a small business program which is being published and which will be run on machines "in the wild".. so we have no control over the actual systems and how they will be used.       

Could anyone advise as to why the .bash_history file isn’t showing my commands, after I’ve run them?  Are there instances where Applescript –to-terminal commands are NOT passed into the bash history?

Comment: `.bash_history` is saved when you exit bash.  at that point, bash saves the history of whatever was read in from .bash_history when you started the shell followed by whatever you typed into the shell itself (subject to the limits imposed by the `$HISTSIZE` and `$HISTFILESIZE` variables). Also, by default, bash will overwrite any existing .bash_history file but can be made to append with `shopt -s histappend` - this means that with histappend off, if you run two bash shells at the same time, the one that exits last will be the one that ends up with its history saved.

Comment: someone said:    Similarly, if "thisismydatastring and my saltbits" is sensitive, don't put that on the command line either. put it in a file and pipe it into openssl.    seems to me, if I was worried about this, and I put either my datastring or my saltbit (or password) into a file, that file would still be on the HDD (and therefore vulnerable), or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, that's why i said it isn't safe from root or users who can acquire root privs.  also why i said using an encrypted fs can help a bit.   and precisely why i pointed out that doing any kind encryption on an untrusted machine is not a good idea.